# how to fix it a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' (python)

Tags: python, django

in my python/django application,i want get information about wallet, but it errors:TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str', could you please tell me how to solve it

views.py:

```
def index(request):      
      get_info_payload = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "params": [], "id": "2", "method": "info"}

      rpc_auth = base64.b64encode("%s:%s" % ("admin", "123456"))
      auth_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': rpc_auth}

      post_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8229/rpc"

      s = Session()


      req = Request('POST', post_url, json=get_info_payload, headers=auth_headers)
      prepped = req.prepare()
      resp = s.send(prepped)

      return HttpResponse(resp.text)
```

Comment: Please update the question with full `Traceback`

Comment: https://www.achain.com/help-en/rpc-tutorial.html#support-for-jsonrpc this is i refer to call rpc in python/django and I want to  display wallet information in localhost for development.

Comment: That wasn't what you were asked. You need to show the full traceback in your question.

Comment: thank you for your response. i solved this but, i have another problem. i want to upload python file in c panel refer by this https://www.webhostinghub.com/help/learn/website/how-tos/creating-a-hello-world-python-script. but i got the result was, my domain suspended in c panel 
and i need to clarify my doubt, in my cpanel account cgi-bin folder have nothing.